# How can I add a subview to another subview and make it appear?

Tags: ios, uiview, scrollview, addsubview

What I am doing it creating a `UIImageView` and hope to add it to a `UIScrollingView` as its scrolling content, but it never appears. So I tried the following code and the problem is now pretty clear to me. How can I add a subview to another subview?

```
 //in myViewController.m
 @synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;
 - (void) viewDidLoad{ 
     UIView* simpleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,200)];
     [simpleView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor BlueColor]];
     [self.view addSubview: simpleView]  //this would work, the simple view appears
     [self.scrollView addSubview: simpleView]  //this would not work, the simple view doesn't appear
 }
```

the scrollView property is hooked up with ScollView in the storyboard, which is the only thing in that controller

Comment: Is your `scrollView` outlet connected in Interface Builder (if you're using IB)?

Comment: unfortunately, yes! It's hooked up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
[self.view addSubview: scrollview]  
[self.scrollView addSubview: simpleView]
```

Basically add one on top of the other not everything is being stacked on the view. Image on top of view on top of self pretty much

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: The scroll view might not be linked to the `scrollView` property from your xib/storyboard.  Set a breakpoint in this method and check it.

Comment: ohoh, thanks for your answer. It is definitely hooked up! I checked it for thousand times....

Answer (score 0):

A view can only have **one** superView.

So when you do this:

```
[self.view addSubview: simpleView];
[self.scrollView addSubview: simpleView];
```

You just set the simpleView superView to self.view then you replace it by self.scrollView. simpleView is no longer the subview of self.view.

As said by ECEsurfer, stack your views:

```
[self.view addSubview: scrollview];
[self.scrollView addSubview: simpleView];
```

Hope it helps !